# Замена символов в Linux sed

Tags: linux, replace

```
*dsdg* **dssdgdsg**
*fghf**gfjfg*
Gngf*jghj**
**fghf*ffgh*
*dgf*nb
**fgfgf**hfh**
```

Нужно, чтобы звезды менялись на (em) только там, где текст стоит в двух звездах (`*dsdq* -> (em)dsdq(em)`) в иных случаях не менять. Есть строка для этого, но она почему-то не работает. Есть идеи?

строка:

```
sed  "s/\*\*/<em>/;s/\*(.*)\*/<em>\1<\/em>/;s/<em>/\*\*/" max.txt
```

ошибка:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 38: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: Stackoverflow убрал звезды в нужных местах

Comment: По существу вопроса: попробуйте поставить обратные косые перед круглыми скобками `\(.*\)` до сих пор не знаю почему это приходится делать, но по другому sed не видит их

Comment: Кстати не ясно как интерпретировать последнюю строку примера как `<em>fgfgf</em>hfh**` или `<em>fgfgf**hfh</em>`

Comment: последний вообще не должен трогать , там же везде по две звезды

Comment: @Mike **попробуйте поставить обратные косые перед круглыми скобками** это сделано намеренно. Логика такая - sed и компания будут в основном применятся програмистами, поэтому, поиск/замена по коду - обычное дело. А в коде (особенно лиспа) скобок хватает.

Comment: @Оля хм. по фразе "_Нужно, чтобы звезды менялись на (em) только там, где текст стоит в двух звездах_" я понял задачу с точностью до наоборот. Может стоило написать "Нужно, чтобы звезды менялись на (em) только там, где текст стоит между одиночными звездами".

Comment: И еще по существу задачи: видимо две звезды стоит менять не на `<em>` а на что нибудь другое, что бы при обратной замене не путались с теми `<em>` что расставлены по делу

Comment: @KoVadim, *Логика такая* — тут не в логике дело, а в стандарте. согласно [**bre**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.A0.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B8.D0.B4.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8_.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B3.D1.83.D0.BB.D1.8F.D1.80.D0.BD.D1.8B.D1.85_.D0.B2.D1.8B.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B9) группа обозначается как `\(текст\)`, а согласно **ege** — как `(текст)`. интерпретатор *sed* обязан понимать опцию `-E`, переключающую на синтаксис **ege**

Comment: ... а у *gnu/sed* есть ещё синонимы той же опции: `-r` и `--regexp-extended`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Вы путаете причину и следствие. Стандарт - это уже следствие, а мой коммент выше - это предпосылка для такого поведения.

Answer (score 2):

если требуемое преобразование:

```
(em)dsdg(em) *(em)dssdgdsg(em)*
(em)fghf(em)(em)gfjfg(em)
Gngf(em)jghj(em)*
*(em)fghf(em)ffgh*
(em)dgf(em)nb
*(em)fgfgf(em)(em)hfh(em)*
```

то получить его с помощью интерпретатора *gnu/sed* можно, например, так:

```
$ sed -r 's/\*([^*]+)\*/(em)\1(em)/g' файл
```

---

если же требуется предварительно обрабатывать ситуацию с **двойными** «звёздочками» (заменяя `**текст**` на, например, `(strong)текст(strong)`), то сделать это можно, например, так:

```
$ sed -r 's/\*\*([^*]+)\*\*/(strong)\1(strong)/g' файл
*dsdg* (strong)dssdgdsg(strong)
*fghf**gfjfg*
Gngf*jghj**
**fghf*ffgh*
*dgf*nb
(strong)fgfgf(strong)hfh**
```

вместе:

```
$ sed -r 's/\*\*([^*]+)\*\*/(strong)\1(strong)/g;s/\*([^*]+)\*/(em)\1(em)/g' файл
(em)dsdg(em) (strong)dssdgdsg(strong)
(em)fghf(em)(em)gfjfg(em)
Gngf(em)jghj(em)*
*(em)fghf(em)ffgh*
(em)dgf(em)nb
(strong)fgfgf(strong)hfh**
```